# CUML RandomForestClassifier TypeError An Integer is required

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use CUML's ensemble RandomForestClassifier to fit my data. When I try and fit, I get a type-error saying an integer is required.

My X_train is a dataframe that I converted to a numpy array and ensured the type is a float32. The original dataframe has only int64 and float32 types, as I used a labelencoder to encode string columns and then removed them.

My Y_train is a series that I converted to a numpy array and tried to make Int32 and Int64 (as I believed that's where the error could be).

```
# Convert X_train DataFrame to numpy array with float32 dtype
X_train_np = X_train.values.astype(np.float32)

# Convert y_train Series to numpy array with float32 dtype
y_train_np = y_train.values


import cuml
from cuml.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from cuml.model_selection import GridSearchCV

# Create the cuML Random Forest classifier
cuml_classifier = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42,n_streams=1)

# Define the parameter grid for grid search
param_grid = {
    'max_depth': [5],
    'n_estimators': [5],
    'split_criterion': ['entropy']
}

# Create the GridSearchCV object
grid_search = GridSearchCV(
    cuml_classifier,
    param_grid=param_grid,
    scoring='roc_auc',
    cv=3,
    return_train_score=True,
    refit="AUC",
    verbose=1
)

# Fit the grid search to the training data
grid_search.fit(X_train_np, y_train_np)
```

```
ValueError: 
All the 3 fits failed.
It is very likely that your model is misconfigured.
You can try to debug the error by setting error_score='raise'.

Below are more details about the failures:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3 fits failed with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/envs/rapids-23.12/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 890, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/rapids-23.12/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nvtx/nvtx.py", line 115, in inner
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/rapids-23.12/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cuml/internals/api_decorators.py", line 188, in wrapper
    ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "randomforestclassifier.pyx", line 463, in cuml.ensemble.randomforestclassifier.RandomForestClassifier.fit
TypeError: an integer is required
```

How to resolve this?

I have checked y_train and all values have a binary 1 or 0 as expected, there are no NaN, None or null values.

Both y_train and X_train are the same length.

I also tried passing X_train as a dataframe and y_train as a series instead of converting to numpy arrays. The same error occurred.

I tried the above and kept the astype("float32") and astype("int32") but that gave the same error.

```
# Create the cuML Random Forest classifier
cuml_classifier = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=5, n_estimators=5,random_state=42)

trained_RF = cuml_classifier.fit(X_train_np, y_train_np)

predictions = cuml_classifier.predict(X_train)

cu_score = cuml.metrics.accuracy_score(y_train,predictions)
sk_score = accuracy_score(y_train.values,predictions)

print( " cuml accuracy: ", cu_score )
print( " sklearn accuracy : ", sk_score )
```

I tried without gridsearch and just directly and it worked without the error. I still need the gridsearch though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the split criterion as defined by scikit-learn however you are using cuml.
Cuml requirers int to define split-criterion:

0 or 'gini' for gini impurity

1 or 'entropy' for information gain (entropy)

2 or 'mse' for mean squared error

4 or 'poisson' for poisson half deviance

5 or 'gamma' for gamma half deviance

6 or 'inverse_gaussian' for inverse gaussian deviance